# Mechanize Ruby Get Text Directly inside Tag

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I have some html that looks something like this

```html
<tr>
  What I want
  <b>
    What I don't want
  </b>
<tr>
```

The code to get the text is

```ruby
my_row = page.search('tr').first

puts my_row.text
```

The issue with this is it will output `What I wantWhat I don't Want`.

How do I extract only the text directly within the tag selected and not the text in any child elements?

Comment: I know with Nokogiri, you could `page.search('tr').xpath('text()')`; you may be able to do something similar with Mechanize.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could access the `tr` tag, then the `b` child tag and remove it, this way you get just the "main" tr content:

```
require 'nokogiri'

data = <<-HTML
<tr>
  What I want
  <b>
    What I don't want
  </b>
<tr>
HTML


doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(data)
tr = doc.css('tr')
tr.css('b').remove
p tr.text
# "\n  What I want\n  \n\n"
```

You could use [`String#strip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-strip) to get a text free of line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use something like Nokogiri for parsing HTML.

https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = "<tr>
  What I want
  <b>
    What I don't want
  </b>
<tr>"

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
text = doc.search('tr').xpath('text()')

puts text.text  # What I want
```

Answer (score 0):

I use child/children for this:

```
doc.at('tr').child.text
```